# Flutter Openweather API Call

Tags: javascript, json, dart, flutter

I'm wanting to parse JSON from the Openweather API.

The Openweather URL is: http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22

I am struggling to find the easiest way of parsing the JSON data to get hold of just the 'description' and 'temp' values.

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make an HTTP request, extract the data, create a map creating only the extracted data:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';

Future<Map> getData() async {
  var httpClient = new HttpClient();
  var request = await httpClient.getUrl(url);
  var response = await request.close();
  var data = json.decode(response);
  var description = data['weather']['description'];
  var temp = data['main']['temp'];
  return { 'description': description, 'temp': temp }; 
}

main() async {
  print(await getData());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gunter, how to I supply the URL to the JSON?

Comment: See the example in https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-io/HttpClient-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library - [weather_pack](https://pub.dev/packages/weather_pack). There are currently two APIs available:

- `api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather`
- `api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall`